# To do or not to do, sample size is the question!

Tags: multilevel-analysis, statistical-power

I have to make a decision about a possible MSc research project. It involves an analysis of secondary data. The project would involve two-level logistic regression. The data would be coming from questionnaires and census surveys.

I have already looked at the variables of interest. I would like to include about 15 potential explanatory variables in an exploratory risk factor analysis. The outcome is disease status.

Working back from the fixed available sample size (I have taken two potential explanatory variables as examples), I have calculated the effective sample size using three different values for the Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (all taken from previous studies).

Taking these approximations of the ICC indicates that the study has sufficient power (≥0.80) to detect a large effect size difference (0.80) over the full range of expected ICCs given an alpha = 0.05.

I'm concerned about whether I should do this study or not. The research question itself has value, lots of value. The data is readily available for use. However, the study will only have sufficient power to detect a statistically significant difference if the effect size is large.

I know there are all sorts of debates as to whether posthoc analysis has value, but is the above power calculation sufficient justification for undertaking the study? What factors should I be considering in my decision-making?

Is the fact that this is an exploratory analysis sufficient justification for "overlooking" the limitations around the study's limited power in those circumstances where the effect size is anything but large?

In this paper here:

*Curr Psychol*. 2020 June ; 39(3): 870–877. doi:10.1007/s12144-018-0018-1. "The Interpretation of Statistical Power after the Data have been Gathered"

Dziak et al., do indeed seem to suggest that where the purpose is exploration, limited power studies are indeed justified. As they say, especially where the only options are using the existing dataset or abandoning an interesting research question.

Would you agree?

Comment: What kind of power does it have for medium and small differences?

Comment: Hi, for a medium effect size (0.5), the power for the two tested variables is between 0.47 - 0.6 for one variable, and between 0.43 - 0.56, for the other, depending on the ICCs (Effective sample size taken). For lower-level effect size (0.2), all power calculations are 15% or less.

Comment: Yikes. Can you get more data?

Comment: I am limited by the fixed sample sizes in the already surveyed population. Does it make any difference that these power calculations are for one variable, whereas I will perform multivariable two-level regression? Is it less of a problem given that I am performing an exploratory hypothesis generation analysis, if you see what I mean?